# Which database is better to use for rest api

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I'm creating rest service for mobile app in java. For storage process which is best suitable for real time storage (Hibernate , JPA & JDBC).

Your valuable answers will put me on right track.

Comment: It depends on what are you trying to do, and what kinds of data are you planning to store.

Comment: I wanted to store address,user Info & images

Comment: JPA and Hibernate both fill the same role, and they're built *on top* of JDBC; your real question is whether you want a framework or to roll your own persistence.

Comment: totally opinion based question, not suitable for SO as per the FAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically ORM technologies like Hibernate, JPA etc., provides greater flexibility to the programmer in maintaining the code say for example, direct mapping to java POJO's, object locking mechanisms, Id generation and lot more with little cost of performance.  If your application needs light weight calls (taking into consideration of concurrency, ofcourse underling database will provide, small relation etc) you could opt JDBC.

Thanks,
JK

Comment: For storing Images JDBC is sutiable

Comment: What do you mean by sorting images and on what criteria you sort images?

Comment: I am talking about storing the image not sorting images.

Comment: Sorry, yes, You use BLOB object to write and read images. If the images are small then fetching images over the network using REST is fine, otherwise it is network intense.

Comment: They actually provide *less* flexibility, but you're not going to be reinventing the wheel.